# Change Behaviour of asynchronous function to synchronous

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-maps, promise

I have a function to get the route information with in same file:-

```
sanGetDirections : function(origin,dest){
        gm.directions({
            origin: origin,
            destination: dest
        }, function(err, data) {
            assert.ifError(err);
            if (data.routes[0] && data.routes[0].legs) {
                 console.log(data.routes[0].legs[ 0 ].distance.text)
                 return data.routes[0].legs[ 0 ].distance.text;
            }               
        })
    }
```

and i want to call this function in a loop:-

```
var distance = module.exports.sanGetDirections(veh_data[key].lat+','+veh_data[key].lng,lat+','+lng);
```

console printing the distance for every call but not returning value . how i can achieve this as synchronously?

Answer (score 0):

Make it a promise. And the use `async/await`.

```
sanGetDirections: function (origin, dest) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        gm.directions({
            origin: origin,
            destination: dest
        }, function (err, data) {
            if(err) rej(err);
            if (data.routes[0] && data.routes[0].legs) {
                console.log(data.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text)
                res(data.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text)
            }
            rej('some error');
        })
    });
}
```

Also you can use `utils.promisify` as well to make the function a promise. And now you can use it in an `async` function.

```
const func = async () => {
    for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
        try{
            const data = await module.exports.sanGetDirections(origin, dest);
        }catch(err){
            // do something with err
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Refer here: https://javascript.info/async-await#await

Comment: may i use it like this :- try{
            const data = await module.exports.sanGetDirections(origin, dest);
        }catch(err){
            // do something with err
            console.log(err);
        }

Comment: Yes you can but you need to use it inside an `async` function. adding a async await function reference doc

Comment: values are coming but in between give this error:- (node:16063) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 107): some error

Comment: i have this function how i can add async and await as reference ? sanGetAssigningDetails : function(req, res,addr,ids,vehh_data,dates, callback){})

Comment: Just mimic what I did in your other functions

Comment: gives error(async function logNumbers() {^^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token function) my node version is :- 6.14.3

Comment: Oh, it's supported after node v7.6